# Show a Toolbar with action items correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to build a simple Toolbar, using the Support Library.

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_share1"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_group"
       app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="Prova2" />

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_share4"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_group_add"
       app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="Prova1" />
</menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:title="Title"
       android:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
       android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500">

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar >

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally
**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       initToolbar();


   }

    private void initToolbar()
    {
        Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "initToolbar");

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_prova);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Calling setSupportActionBar(toolbar) produces this result
[image: navigationIcon is not shown]

without the navigation icon, while commenting that line produces only the 2 action items on the right.

I would like to have the action items, the nav. icon on the left and the title of the toolbar. Why are not showing together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to a misture of all your suggestions.
Now i have

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initToolbar();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_prova, menu);

    return true;
}

private void initToolbar()
{
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);

    if (toolbar != null) {

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle("Title");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("Sub");            


    }
}
}
```

And the result: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting a toolbar as the action bar means that you should not be using `inflateMenu` and instead should be using the established action bar hook methods to inflate it.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_prova, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

can show the nav

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    enter code hereprivate Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For  the nav. icon on the left  and title**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        toolbar.setTitle("abc");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**and  for action items use option menu code**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_prova, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch(item.getItemId())
{
case R.id.menu_share1:
//code;
break;
case R.id.menu_share4:
//code;
break;
default:
break;
}

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```